# jQuery Function not triggering on first page load, but triggering fine on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using the function below to set equal height columns on grid rows. On initial page load, the function sets a height of '0' on `div.gallery-item`. On refresh, the function kicks in properly and assigns the height as set out in the function.

Here's the script:

```
/* Responsive equal height columns for gallery (http://css-tricks.com/examples/EqualHeightsInRows/) */

var currentTallest = 0,
currentRowStart = 0,
rowDivs = new Array();

function setConformingHeight(el, newHeight) {
// set the height to something new, but remember the original height in case things     change
el.data("originalHeight", (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight")));
el.height(newHeight);
}

function getOriginalHeight(el) {
// if the height has changed, send the originalHeight
return (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight"));
}

function columnConform() {

// find the tallest DIV in the row, and set the heights of all of the DIVs to match it.
$('div.gallery-item').each(function() {

    // "caching"
    var $el = $(this);

    var topPosition = $el.position().top;

    if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {

        // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
        for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

        // set the variables for the new row
        rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
        currentRowStart = topPosition;
        currentTallest = getOriginalHeight($el);
        rowDivs.push($el);

    } else {

        // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
        rowDivs.push($el);
        currentTallest = (currentTallest < getOriginalHeight($el)) ? (getOriginalHeight($el)) : (currentTallest);

    }
    // do the last row
    for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

});

}


$(window).resize(function() {
columnConform();
});

$(function() {
columnConform();
});
```

I know this is something to do with how I'm loading the function. The advice on the article I took this script from was to use `window.onload` if images are what is setting the varying heights on the columns, but I've tried adding that to the last part of the script, as below, and the function doesn't trigger at all.

```
$(window).onload = (function() {
columnConform();
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: Try $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

`window.onload = columnConform;`

instead of:

```
$(function () {
    columnConform();
});
```

This way, size of images, and so parent container, will be relevant.

Comment: I've given this a go, and it works, but there's a flash of the content without equal height columns on load. Is there a way to only show content after the script has done it's thing?

I used `$(function() {
 window.onload = columnConform;
});`

Comment: Ya, hide it by default, show it once onload handler is called. EDIT: but don't nest it inside ready handler, this is useless (`$(function() {...});` being shorthand for ready handler!). So i mean, just use `window.onload = columnConform;`. FYI, to avoid flash usually websites use some kind of loading animation, you have to implement it following your own logic.

Comment: Thanks. I assume you'd go about that by setting `display:none;` for each div by default and then adding `display:block` along with the height in the `columnConform;` function?

Comment: @jasonbradberry I'm sorry cannot help you more as i don't know exactly how is displayed your website but ya, that's a possibility even it will produce a UI reflow

Comment: Have adjusted to just use `window.onload = columnConform;`, thanks. Was sure it didn't work first time I tried it like that, but I think it was due to the delay.

Comment: Ok, I've realised setting `display:none;` is a bad idea in case of no JS. Will give it some thought!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stashing your code in the `$( document ).ready( handler )` segment rather than onload?

Read more about `.ready()` at the [jQuery Docs page](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).